# Error messages not getting removed on reloading the page,when I've overridden the view with a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, error-messages

I have overridden the standard view of Account object with a visualforce page,& using a custom button that is used to send email to Account,using a custom field,Email__c.The error appears if we've not filled the Email__c field & try to send email.On reload of page showing the error,I want the message to be removed.But the page appears again with the error message.What can I do?

> My code is as follows:

```
    public with sharing class sendEmailToAccount {
    ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public sendEmailToAccount(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;


    }


    public PageReference sendEmailToAccount() {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


        List<Account> lstaccount = [select id,Test_Email_Field__c,Name,AccountNumber from Account where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

        if(lstaccount[0].Test_Email_Field__c==null)
        {

            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Cannot Send email when Email field is empty.'));
             return null;


        }

        if(lstaccount[0].Test_Email_Field__c!=null)
        {
            String accName=String.valueOf(lstaccount[0].Name);
            String accNumber=String.valueOf(lstaccount[0].AccountNumber);
            String accOwner=String.valueOf(lstaccount[0].Name);
            String toAddress=String.valueOf(lstaccount[0].Test_Email_Field__c);
            EmailTemplate et=[select Id, subject,body,HtmlValue from EmailTemplate where id='00X28000000R3VZ'];


            String subjectTemplate= et.subject;
            String contentTemplate=et.body;
            String htmlcontent=et.HtmlValue;
            String filteredcontent=contentTemplate.replace('{!Account.Name}',accName);
            String filteredcontent1=filteredcontent.replace('{!Account.Id}',accOwner);
            String filteredcontent2=filteredcontent1.replace('{!Account.AccountNumber}',accNumber); 


            message.ToAddresses=new String[]{toAddress};
            message.subject=subjectTemplate;
            message.PlainTextBody=filteredcontent2;
            message.HtmlBody=htmlcontent;

             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Confirm,'Email sent successfully !'));
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message });

             return null;


        }


        return controller.view();

    }

}
```

---

VF Page

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="sendEmailToAccount" action="{!sendEmailToAccount}">
    <apex:pageMessages id="messages" />
   <apex:detail relatedList="true"/>
   </apex:page>
```

---

JavaScript Code:

```
if(confirm("Are you sure You want to send Email?"))
 {
  window.open('/apex/SendEmailToAccount?id={!Account.Id}','_self');
}
```

---

[image: Error message does not disappears on reloading the page]

[image: Executed JavaScript on click of button]

Comment: how `sendEmailToAccount` method getting invoked?

Comment: Hello @Ratan,You could see a 'Send Email To Account' button on the Account Detail page,which is executing a javascript that asks us for confirmation of sending email,when we confirm our action ,a visualforce page is called,whose extension is provided above

Comment: Can you please add JavaScript and visuaforce page code as well it hard to understand the flow

Comment: Hello ,I 've added JavaScript and Visualforce page code.

Comment: since you are calling the `sendEmailToAccount` method from apex:page action attribute. On page load it will always check for the Account email address and if address is not present then it will give error.. I think you can just use that javascript button and show alert message if email is null and you could use webservice for sending emails

Comment: And then the similar case with Email Sent Successfully message,every time i reload the page,it appears as it is.Are both these cases similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VisualForce page you have created to override the Account view is calling the `sendEmailToAccount()` method every time the page loads because of the `action="{! sendEmailToAccount}"` line within your `<apex:page >` parameters which is why you see this error every time you re-load the page.

If you are wanting to have the page display a warning message every time the account is viewed then you may wish to create some form of `verifyEmailDetails()` method which is called upon page load which verifies the required fields and pops up a warning message if needed, you could then create a separate  `sendEmailToAccount()` method which then re-verifies and then sends the email to make sure that the account is still / now valid if edits have been made.

Alternatively to having your validation upon viewing the account you may be better off sticking with the standard salesforce view and having your confirm / validations in a separate page upon the click of the **Send Email to Account Holder** button.